# Velvet Optimizer automatically changes to hash-length 31

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to use Velvet Optimizer for a De Novo Assembly; I set my hash-lengths to be between 55 and 69

```
/projects/path/to/perlscripts/VelvetOptimiser-2.2.6/VelvetOptimiser.pl -s 55 -e 69 -f '-shortPaired -fastq.gz -separate trial2.trimmed.paired.R1.fastq.gz trial2.trimmed.paired.R2.fastq.gz' -f '-short -fastq.gz trial2.trimmed.unpaired.R1.fastq.gz' -f '-short -fastq.gz trial2.trimmed.unpaired.R2.fastq.gz' -x 2
```

When I check the output file, it returns me with

```
Starting to check input parameters.
    Start hash value too high.  New start hash value is 31.
    End hash value not in workable range.  New end hash value is 31
```

Any idea where I could be going wrong in my command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a value for `MAXKMERLENGTH` was not set when compiling `velveth`, VelvetOptimizer just uses the default `$maxhash` value of 31<sup>[1](https://github.com/tseemann/VelvetOptimiser/blob/2.2.6/VelvetOptimiser.pl#L110-L112)</sup>. The hash lengths that you specify on the command line must be less than or equal to this value to run the tool successfully. The solution is to re-compile `velveth` with a larger `MAXKMERLENGTH`, for example:

```
make 'MAXKMERLENGTH=69'
```

Alternatively, re-install using the [bioconda](/questions/tagged/bioconda) package manager:

```
conda install -c bioconda perl-velvetoptimiser
```

This package includes [velvet](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/velvet), which is built using a much higher maximum k-mer length and is usually sufficient for most purposes: `MAXKMERLENGTH=191`<sup>[2](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/blob/master/recipes/velvet/build.sh)</sup>.